# How to find the higher numbers in an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to reach the higher numbers in an object.

```
let object1 = {
  a: 2,
  b: 2,
  c: 0,
  d: 3,
  e: 1,
  f: 1
}
// Need to get 2,2,3 above. The first 3 highest ones.
let object2 = {
  a: 7,
  b: 15,
  c: 1,
  d: 7,
  e: 4,
  f: 3
}
// 15,7,7 above.
```

But it is not like return > 1 because I cannot set an exact number; the object can be

```
let object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 0,
  d: 2,
  e: 0,
  f: 0
}
```

I have tried it like keys.reduce but I could not reach out to a good solution.

Comment: You would benefit from keeping the data in an Array instead of such an Object. Then you can make use of the Array.sort() method. Also try to get familiar with basic implementations of sorting yourself - you will see that the problem above is simple to solve.

If you need to keep the data in an Object first make sure you know how to iterate on it's keys

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 0,
  d: 2,
  e: 0,
  f: 0
}

console.log(Object.values(input).sort((x, y) => y - x).slice(0, 3));
```

You can use `sort` against the values of the object. First use Object.values to change your object values into an array then run a sort against it with a slice to fetch first 3 highest values.

```
Object.values(input).sort((x, y) => y - x).slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: you need no extra wrapping.